# how to check if a value exist in QList?

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

I have a class to save the ID of customer and his name. After saving I'm inserting the object into a `QList` and viewing them on table.

**What I need:**

I need to check if the customer is already added to the table or not.

**My approach:**

I'm trying to search the list using the customer ID and if I find it I want to update his record otherwise add a new one.

The code should look something like this.

```
bool customerExist = customersList.contains(customerID);

if (!customerExist) 
{
    customersList.append(customer)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to access your data through a customerID regularly, I would recommend to use a `QMap<int, Customer*>`. (use as key the type of your customerID)

Using a QMap will be much faster if the number of customers is getting large.

Then you can do something like::

```
if (!myMap.contains(customerID))
{
    myMap.insert(customerID, customer);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can search in the list by doing:

```
auto iterator = std::find_if(
  customersList.begin(), customersList.end(),
  [](MyObject x) { return x.myproperty() == customerID; }
);
if (iterator != customersList.end())
```